# mysql update REPLACE with concat

Tags: php, mysql, replace

my table save same ID like that : 123,9901,888,99

I need change some id in this field

I using my sql :  let 9901 change to 2001

```
UPDATE `TALBE_` SET id_group = REPLACE (id_group, '9901', '2001');
```

That's work

but, I change 99 to 100

```
UPDATE `TALBE_` SET id_group = REPLACE (id_group, '99', '100');
```

My sql fidle had changed to

123,**10001**,888,**100**

how to just change 99 -> 100, dont change 9901?

Do I need use concat?

But I test some time still cant do that

Comment: Never store multiple values in a single field. Changing your table design is the only real solution to this problem

Comment: Thank you for your reminder
but, the urgent need to use this sql I need to modify the system occurred

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use e.g.

```
UPDATE `TALBE_` SET id_group = 
    trim(',' from REPLACE(concat(',', id_group, ','), ',99,', ',100,'));
```

Comment: Thank you, thanks for you let me know I can use trim()

Answer (score 1):

her a version that seeks the number a replace it

You must insert the search value 2 times

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS (',',
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(id_group, ',', FIND_IN_SET('888',id_group)-1)
      ,'100',
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(id_group, ',', --1* (LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(id_group,'[0-9]','')) -(FIND_IN_SET('888',id_group)-1)))
      );
```

**Sample**

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT CONCAT_WS (',',
    ->       SUBSTRING_INDEX('123,9901,888,99', ',', FIND_IN_SET('888','123,9901,888,99')-1)
    ->       ,'100',
    ->       SUBSTRING_INDEX('123,9901,888,99', ',', --1* (LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE('123,9901,888,99','[0-9]','')) -(FIND_IN_SET('888','123,9901,888,99')-1)))
    ->       );
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| CONCAT_WS (',',
      SUBSTRING_INDEX('123,9901,888,99', ',', FIND_IN_SET('888','123,9901,888,99')-1)
      ,'100',
      SUBSTRING_INDEX('123,9901,888,99', ',', --1* (LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE('123,9901,888,99','[0-9]','')) -(FIND_IN_SET('888','123,9901,888,9 |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 123,9901,100,123                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]>
```